# Php writing txt file writes first file but not the second

Tags: php, file-io

Hey all i am wondering why my code below is only writing the first but does not write the second file

```
$counterFile = 'counter.log';
$counterFileBU = 'counterBU.log';

if(!is_writable($counterFile)) {
    $count = 'WErr';
}
else {
    $count = file_get_contents($counterFile);
    $count++;
    file_put_contents($counterFile, $count);
    file_put_contents($counterFileBU, $count . ' @ ' . date("F j, Y, g:i a"));
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: any warning/error during script execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would not run and would not output anything if this condition is not meet ?

```
 if(!is_writable($counterFile)) {
```

You should try trigger some error

```
$counterFile = __DIR__ . '/counter.log';
$counterFileBU = __DIR__ . '/counterBU.log';

touch($counterFile);
touch($counterFileBU);

if(!is_writable($counterFile) || !is_writable($counterFileBU) ) {
   throw new Exception("Not Writable");
}
```

Comment: That is correct. It was being blocked i guess by the first one.

Comment: @StealthRT .. Glad i was able to help